# Fazer texto ter quebra de linha dentro da div

Tags: css

Bom preciso fazer com que o texto que esta dentro da div da classe `txt` tenha quebra de linha. Segue o exemplo do código que tenho que alterar.

```css
.font-15, input, textarea, select, .container-head, .se-pre-con p, .dialogboxbody, .top_menu .scroll div, .autocomplete-suggestion .txt {
    font-size: 15px;
}
.shadow-2, .bt:hover, .context_menu_pai, .box_login, .datepicker.dropdown-menu, .dialogbox, .overflow-menu ul, .autocomplete-suggestions {
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.material-icons.large { 
    font-size: 6rem; 
    width: 6rem;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.autocomplete-suggestions {
  text-align: left;
  cursor: default;
  border-top: 0;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  position: absolute;
  max-height: 254px;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.autocomplete-suggestion {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 23px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  font-size: 1.02em;
  color: #484848;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #D7D7D7;
}
.autocomplete-suggestion .img {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  border-right: 1px solid #D7D7D7;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
.autocomplete-suggestion .img img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.autocomplete-suggestion .txt {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.autocomplete-suggestion .txt div {
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.autocomplete-suggestion b {
  color: #0091FF;
}
.autocomplete-suggestion.selected {
  background: #EDEDED;
  border-right: 7px solid #0091FF;
}
```

```html
<!-- Material Icons (Google) -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="autocomplete-suggestions">
  <div class="autocomplete-suggestion">
    <div class="img"><i class="material-icons large">face</i>
    </div>
    <div class="txt">
      <div>DES NIVEA ROLL-ON FEM. SENSITIVE & PURE 50ML</div>
      TEXTO EXTRA
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Um simples `white-space: normal` na div resolverá o problema.

EDIT:

Dentro da classe `.autocomplete-suggestion` possui um `white-space: nowrap` que está impedindo a quebra de linha automática. Remova ela.

O correto é usar `<p>` como @Cleiton mencionou. `<div>` não comporta corretamente texto diretamente.

```css
.font-15, input, textarea, select, .container-head, .se-pre-con p, .dialogboxbody, .top_menu .scroll div, .autocomplete-suggestion .txt {
    font-size: 15px;
}
.shadow-2, .bt:hover, .context_menu_pai, .box_login, .datepicker.dropdown-menu, .dialogbox, .overflow-menu ul, .autocomplete-suggestions {
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}
.material-icons.large {
    font-size: 6rem;
    width: 6rem;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.autocomplete-suggestions {
    text-align: left;
    cursor: default;
    border-top: 0;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute;
    max-height: 254px;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.autocomplete-suggestion {
    position: relative;
    line-height: 23px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    font-size: 1.02em;
    color: #484848;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #D7D7D7;
}
.autocomplete-suggestion .img {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    border-right: 1px solid #D7D7D7;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
.autocomplete-suggestion .img img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
.autocomplete-suggestion .txt {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.autocomplete-suggestion .txt div {
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.autocomplete-suggestion b {
    color: #0091FF;
}
.autocomplete-suggestion.selected {
    background: #EDEDED;
    border-right: 7px solid #0091FF;
}
```

```html
<!-- Material Icons (Google) -->

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="autocomplete-suggestions">
    <div class="autocomplete-suggestion">
        <div class="img"><i class="material-icons large">face</i>
        </div>
        <div class="txt">
            <p>DES NIVEA ROLL-ON FEM. SENSITIVE & PURE 50ML</p>
            TEXTO EXTRA
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Da sua forma deu certo, só que quando o texto e muito grande a linha vertical que esta do lado do icone não acompanha a div 'autocomplete-suggestion', tem como resolver isso? Eu tentei usar o '<p>' porém ele pulava uma linha e não ficava organizado.

Comment: Cria um JSFiddle com o texto grande para mim ver. Quando ao `p` não ficar organizado, creio que você possa alterar o `margin` para resolver.

Comment: ok, coloquei 'width: 300px;' dentro da 'autocomplete-suggestion' para simular o erro ok. segue o link: https://jsfiddle.net/kpa997tn/

Comment: Fiz uma gambiarra só para saber se isso que você quer: https://jsfiddle.net/kpa997tn/1/

Comment: eu te mandei o link errado, o certo e esse aqui:https://jsfiddle.net/kpa997tn/2/ . Percebi que vc colocou um tamanho fixo, deu certo porém as janelas não vão ter o mesmo tamanho, pois depende do tamanho do texto.

Comment: Por isso  a gambiarra :) Que tal criar outra pergunta com esse problema? Futuramente poderá ajudar outras pessoas.

Comment: acabei de fazer isso: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/174237/como-deixar-linha-vertical-do-tamanho-da-div

Answer (score 0):

O `<p></p>` serve exatamente para isso. Você também pode separar os conteúdos com `display:block` usando `<span></span>`, atribuindo uma classe exclusivamente para isso. Caso uma dessas formas perca a formatação, é porque o seu CSS já veio "carregado". Recomendo que dê uma limpada no CSS deles e depois customize de novo, para ter certeza que não haja algum framework ou arquivo css fazendo o que você não precisa.

Comment: Mesmo usando o `<p>` ao invés do `<div>` o conteúdo ainda não quebra de linha.

Comment: Eu achei o motivo do `<p>` não quebrar a linha, coloquei na minha resposta.

Answer (score -3):

```
<p style="white-space: pre-line;">
  DES NIVEA ROLL-ON FEM. SENSITIVE & PURE 50ML TEXTO EXTRA
</p>
```

Comment: Sugiro que dê uma olhada em [answer] e [Por que e como algumas respostas são excluídas](/help/deleted-answers)